# Next.js using apollo client cache in getServerSideProps

Tags: next.js, apollo-client

I'm using Next.js with apollo client. I need to create a seamless workflow between server and client side. In my ssr page, I run a query in getServerSideProps and send the created apollo cache to browser like below;

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context: GetServerSidePropsContext) {
  const apolloClient = initializeApollo();

  await apolloClient.query({
    query: CitiesQuery,
    variables: {
      name: cityParamVar(),
    },
  });

  return {
    props: {
      initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
    },
  };
}
```

On the client side, I have my apollo cache already filled with query data, wonderful!.
Then, I run a second query on client side, so apollo cache will have my second query results as well.
Then, I navigate to Home page and then come back to my page again. Of course getServerSideProps  will run again. Here, in getServerSideProps  function, is it possible to obtain the same apollo cached filled with my second query results, that was run on client side?

Can we create a totally seamless workflow between client & server?

I saw samples just run **const apolloClient = initializeApollo()** in getServerSideProps. So, I won't have the updated cache! Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, there doesn't seem to be a clean way to do it at this point. I've been looking into a way to solve the same issue while using React Query.

This [feature request discussion at Next.js GitHub repo](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19611) should provide some useful background information. There's also a couple of hacky workarounds which you could try.

Comment: getSession  returns the updated session, in getServerProps. Very good. However,  getToken  returns  the old session token  from cookie! I need the token be refreshed as well when I refresh the token!

Comment: Please consider putting the important bits of the reference you cite in your answer, for posterity.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk If I knew a specific snippet from the referenced link to solve this parrtical issue, I would have included it but thanks for pointing this out. As a new to contributing here, would it have been more appropriate to just comment instead of answering?